# passing multidimensional NpgsqlParameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, npgsql

I have the following working c# code in an asp.net core project:

```
... /* words is of type List<string> */
var query = $"SELECT * FROM a_table WHERE word = ANY(@words) AND token = 'some string'";
using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, connection);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@words", NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlDbType.Text).Value = words;
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ...
```

This works. I'm checking if the word's result is cached when the token is precise `something else`.

The problem begins when the `token` is different for each word in `words`. I would like to check the database for any matches. The following SQL works when I run it in the database directly:

```
SELECT * FROM a_table WHERE (word, token) IN (('able', 'something else'), ('pizza', 'something else entirely'))
```

And I now want to use it in c# like this:

```
... /* words was a List<> of a custom type with two string auto properties, but I changed it to List<List<string>> when that didn't work. Didn't help much. */
var query = $"SELECT * FROM a_table WHERE (word, token) IN @words";
using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, connection);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@words", NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlDbType.Text).Value = words;
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ...
```

But I guess npgsql can't handle that - there's no type that's an array of arrays of strings?

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
>         Connection id "0HLFDVA1DP743", Request id "0HLFDVA1DP743:00000002": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
>   System.Exception: While trying to write an array, one of its elements failed validation. You may be trying to mix types in a non-generic IList, or to write a jagged array. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Can't write CLR type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] with handler type TextHandler
>      at lambda_method(Closure , NpgsqlTypeHandler , Object , NpgsqlLengthCache& , NpgsqlParameter )
>   ...

Is there a proper way of passing in a multidimensional array? Or do I have to build it myself, and lose the injection protection? I thought parameters were supposed to make this whole thing simpler! Note that I also don't know how many items will be in the words list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I guess npgsql can't handle that - there's no type that's an array of arrays of strings?

PostgreSQL supports multidimensional arrays (`int[,]`), but not jagged arrays (`int[][]`).

> Is there a proper way of passing in a multidimensional array?

Yes, here's an [example](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/b0c56e4b1320c2c005482970bb9042e1f71ecb9d/test/Npgsql.Tests/Types/ArrayTests.cs#L202-L220):

```
[Test, Description("Roundtrips a two-dimensional array of ints")]
public void TwoDimensionalInts()
{
    using (var conn = OpenConnection())
    using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT @p1, @p2", conn))
    {
        var expected = new[,] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
        var p1 = new NpgsqlParameter("p1", NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlDbType.Integer);
        var p2 = new NpgsqlParameter { ParameterName = "p2", Value = expected };
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);
        p1.Value = expected;
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        Assert.That(reader.GetValue(0), Is.EqualTo(expected));
        Assert.That(reader.GetProviderSpecificValue(0), Is.EqualTo(expected));
        Assert.That(reader.GetFieldValue<int[,]>(0), Is.EqualTo(expected));
    }
}
```

> The following SQL works when I run it in the database directly:
>
> ```
> SELECT * 
> FROM a_table 
> WHERE (word, token) IN (('able', 'something else'), ('pizza', 'something else entirely'))
> ```

That does work...but it doesn't involve any arrays. You're searching for a row in a collection of rows:

```
postgres=# SELECT ('able', 'something else');

           row
-------------------------
 (able,"something else")
(1 row)


postgres=# SELECT (0, 1) IN (u.t) FROM (SELECT unnest(ARRAY[(0, 1), (2, 3)]) AS t) AS u;

 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Comment: `doesn't involve arrays` -> Yes... but that is the syntax I'm trying to get Npgsql to generate, just with proper escaping. So passing an array is wrong?

Comment: Accepted because switching my `words` object got me past that error, I'll make a new question about passing a record as a parameter.

Comment: Note that Npgsql doesn't generate any SQL for you, ever - the user supplies the SQL. And as @austin-drenski wrote above, rows and arrays are very different things in PostgreSQL: you can convert on to the other but they are distinct things.

Comment: @ShayRojansky how do you compare records and arrays[]?

Comment: I was going to ask another question but I would basically be reposting the first 2/3 of this one and asking a different question...

Comment: Looking at your original example, why not just pass two regular arrays, one for words and one for tokens, and do a simple `word = ANY(@words) AND token = ANY(@tokens)`?

Comment: @ShayRojansky because the tokens are different per word, they have to match at the same index

Comment: Have you tried `unnest` as suggested by @austin-drenski above?